# svg mask and bounding box

Tags: svg, mask, bounding-box

I need to apply mask to a different objects.
Mask should cover whole object (visible part of it). I put the mask inside one specific place, at the top of the page, changed `maskContentUnits` to `objectBoundingBox`, so it worked perfectly.

But then a problem appeared.

I made a fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8qdt7vjr/1/

```
<body>
    <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask1" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <ellipse cx=".5" cy=".5" rx=".5" ry=".5" fill="white" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <svg class="svg" width="200" height="150" overflow="visible">
        <rect x="-50" y="-50" width="350" height="250" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" />
        <svg id="zzz" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" overflow="visible" mask="url(#mask1)">
            <rect x="-50" y="-50" width="350" height="250" fill="blue" fill-opacity=".3" />
        </svg>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

In this fiddle i want to apply mask to svg element with `id="zzz"`. But inside this element there is a `rect` element, that increases **zzz**'s bounding box. In the fiddle it is `rect`, but in my project it is an `image` tag. **zzz** has overflow set to hidden (in the fiddle I changed it to visible, so it is easier to see the problem), so I have a specific portion of image visible inside **zzz**.

The real problem is that **zzz**'s inner content increases **zzz**'s bounding box.
In the fiddle I want ellipse mask to be inside red rectangle (visible **zzz**'s area), but it is inside green rectangle (**zzz**'s bounding box) instead.

So the main question is: is there any way to achieve this goal? Mask will be used by many elements with different sizes and content and I do not want to clone it.

Is there any way to do this without cloning mask inside each element?
Is there any way to reduce bounding box to visible area?
Is there any way to show a part of an image without expanding parent's bounding box?
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The answer to the second and third parts is no to both. That makes answering the first and fourth cases rather difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you try to achieve?

```html
<body>
    <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask1" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <ellipse cx="100" cy="75" rx="100" ry="75" fill="white" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <svg class="svg" width="200" height="150" overflow="visible">
        <rect x="-50" y="-50" width="350" height="250" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" />
        <svg id="zzz" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" overflow="visible" mask="url(#mask1)">
            <rect x="-50" y="-50" width="350" height="250" fill="blue" fill-opacity=".3" />
        </svg>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

Maybe using userSpaceOnUse instead of objectBoundingBox can help achieve what you want... In combination with nested svg elements you can define the userspace to use and with that the part the mask is applied to...

Comment: This is the way I am using now. But in my case I do not know the dimensions of `svg` that has a `mask` tag. In fact there are several different elements with the same mask. I use clone of original mask for each element now, and I want to avoid cloning.

Comment: userSpaceOnUse is the coordinate system of the element where the mask is applied to, not where it comes from. In you case it would be zzz's parent svg element.
Maybe you can post an exapmle, where userSpaceOn use is not working?

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/04nz92d9/  
  
Mask cannot be correctly applied to both elements: **zzz1** and **zzz2**. With `maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` it can be done easily, but there is a problem with bounding box expanded by block content.

Comment: mmh,  i was thinking along the lines of using userSpaceOnUse in combination with percentage values inside the mask. From my understanding the percentages should be relative to the user coordinate system for the element referencing the <mask> element, which unfortunately isn't implemented like this :-(

Comment: Yes, one may think, according to help, that inside mask used coordinate system from the element referencing the mask using `mask` attribute. Unfortunately either my english is too bad and I can't understand help correctly or help is somehow wrong. Mask content using coordinate system from the place the mask defined. It can be easily tested: http://jsfiddle.net/lazyeugene/wq1gg29j/
So, to apply single mask to many different elements I need to clone it inside those elements so the mask will use element's coordinate system for percentage values.